# want a sql to UPDATE a SUBSTRING

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I have a table called calendar with a column DateTo
This has format 2014-02-19T16:00:00 (varchar and can not be changed)
I would like to set time to 13:00

I've tried

```
UPDATE calendar 
SET DateTo = (SUBSTRING(DateTo FROM 1 FOR 11) + '13:00') 
WHERE SUBSTRING(DateFrom FROM 1 FOR 10) = '2014-02-19'
```

Thinking this would give me:

2014-02-19T13:00

but instead it returns 2027?

Comment: Try using `CONCAT(SUBSTRING(), '13:00')` instead of `+ '13:00'` *(Your use of the `+` operator is causing your values to be **implicitly** cast to numeric values [yielding `2014` and `13`], added together [yielding `2027`], and then assigned to a VARCHAR column, causing another **implicit** cast from the numeric back to a VARCHAR [yielding `'2027'`].)*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do as

```
update 
calendar
set DateTo = concat(
  substring_index(DateTo,'T',1),'T','13:00'
)
where substring_index(DateTo,'T',1) = '2014-02-19'
;
```

**[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6f762/1)**

As **MatBailie** suggested instead of

```
where substring_index(DateTo,'T',1) = '2014-02-19'
```

its better to use

`WHERE DateTo LIKE '2014-02-19T%'`

This will be significantly faster if there is an index on DateTo

Comment: `WHERE DateTo LIKE '2014-02-19T%'` will be significantly faster if there is an index on `DateTo`.